# Is it possible to obtain a Navigation Bars current "barTintColor"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I am trying to create a unit test for my app that checks the color of the Navigation Bar and compares it to the User Defaults saved for the theme color within the app.

I can't seem to find a way to access the bars current color. Is this even possible?

```
- (void) testColorThemeNavigationBar {
    UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
    MSMColorManager *manager = [[MSMColorManager alloc]init];
    navigationBar = [manager getNavBar];

    UIColor *navBarColor = [[UIColor alloc]init];
    UIColor *currentThemeColor = [[UIColor alloc] init];

    navBarColor = navigationBar.barTintColor;
    currentThemeColor = [manager themeColor];

    XCTAssertEqualObjects(navBarColor, currentThemeColor);
}
```

Right now my test fails saying that the value for the navBarColor is null, while my currentThemeColor is populated with the correct UIColorObject. I believe this is because the barTintColor method is only used for setting a color, not retrieving.

I also tried backgroundColor to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you used your debugger? What is the value for `navigationBar`? It's probably `nil`. And why do you create a nav bar just to throw it away and get a nav bar from the `MSColorManager`?

Answer (score 1):

As i have used theme based setting in one of my app here what I have done so far to get `navigationBar` tint color.

**Get Navigation bar tint color:**

```
AppDelegate *objPCAppDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;  
NSLog(@"%@",[objPCAppDelegate.window rootViewController]);

UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*)[objPCAppDelegate.window rootViewController];
NSLog(@"%@",navController.navigationBar.barTintColor);
```

Don't create New object of  `UINavigationController` just get form your `application.window` and use it in your test case.

**Note: if you are using default color of navigation bar that it will always return `nil` as there is no color for default navigation bar.**

To get color you have to set custom color to navigation bar than & than you can get it in your test case.